# How do I use a server apiKey with Chrome Store API?

Tags: powershell, google-api

I generated an server key for Chrome Store API in the Developer Dashboard. I would like to publish a .zip file containing my extension programmatically. The instructions in https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api show OAuth, Bearer token authentication. How can I use the server key instead?

Things I tried: header "X-ApiKey" = "$apiKey", adding ?key=$apiKey, etc.

In all cases

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login
>   Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login
>   Required"}}

For this example I have been using Powershell Invoke-RestMethod

```
$headers = @{
    "X-ApiKey" = $apiKey
    "X-Goog-Api-Version" = "2"
}
$endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$appId/?key=$apiKey"
Write-Host $endpoint

$response = Invoke-RestMethod $endpoint -Method Put -InFile $filePath -Headers $headers
```

More docs, and no clues - https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. API keys are only used to access public data. To use the Chrome Store API, you must authenticate as the user who you wish to publish the app as and, thus, you must supply an OAuth token. Check out [the OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for an example of how to get an OAuth token.